# What am i doing wrong with this Angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have now tried this for a few hours what should be so easy but i do not understand why i dont get this working.

The dummy list is just for testing that it should work and it does. However not when i connect my server side data source. The Json returned by the ajax call is identical to the one in the dummy list.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is a link to working example with dummylist: http://plnkr.co/edit/6nBkdBpPVqQ2P8u2BEeY

Server side is an .NET MVC 4 app.

HTML:

```
 <div data-ng-controller="currencyController">
     <ul>

       <li data-ng-repeat="currency in currencies"><span>{{ currency.CurrencyCode}} - </span><span>{{ currency.CurrencyName }}</span>
   </li>

     </ul>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var currencyTools = angular.module('currencyTools', []);

currencyTools.controller('currencyController',function(currencyService,$scope) {
   var path = 'currency/GetCurrencies';
   currencyService.getAllCurrencies(path, function (jsonResult) {
        $scope.currencies = jsonResult.data;
    });
   // $scope.currencies = dummyList(); //if i uncomment this it works
})





currencyTools.factory('currencyService', function () {
    var service = {
        getAllCurrencies: function (path, callback) {
            var result = $.ajax({
                url: path,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(json) { callback(json); }
            });
            return result;
        }
    };
    return service;
});


function dummyList() {
    return [
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BAM", "CurrencyName": "Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark" },
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BBD", "CurrencyName": "Barbadian Dollar" }, 
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BDT", "CurrencyName": "Bangladeshi Taka" },
    { "CurrencyCode": "BGN", "CurrencyName": "Bulgarian Lev" },
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BHD", "CurrencyName": "Bahraini Dinar" },
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BIF", "CurrencyName": "Burundian Franc" }, 
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BMD", "CurrencyName": "Bermudan Dollar" }, 
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BND", "CurrencyName": "Brunei Dollar" }, 
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BOB", "CurrencyName": "Bolivian Boliviano" },
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BRL", "CurrencyName": "Brazilian Real" }, 
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BSD", "CurrencyName": "Bahamian Dollar" }, 
    {  "CurrencyCode": "BTC", "CurrencyName": "Bitcoin" }];
}
```

Comment: I would suggest examining the problem further. Try using a javascript debugger to inspect values at various points in your function. For example, I would be curious to know the value of `jsonResult.data` in your success callback.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going wrong here.

1. `$.ajax` is an asynchronous call that returns a promise, not a value. So you're `getAllCurrencies` method is returning a promise. What you'd really need to do is subscribe to that promise's `success()` function and wait for the values to return from the server.  ... BUT...
2. Don't use JQuery to do your AJAX in an Angular application. You should almost never need to do that. Use `$http` instead. It will make sure a digest is triggered after the ajax is returned.
3. If you *must* use JQuery's AJAX, you'd have to use `$apply` after you update your scope.

[Here's an updated plunker with an example of doing it in a more "angular" way.](http://plnkr.co/edit/10NfTu7YsfPv1PzYFZgc?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and solution. My brain has been going WTF#!#! for a few hours now :) That $http was totally new for me, first time trying out Angular. cheers!